# Phillipines visa 2 weeks

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, philippines, manila

Do I need a visa for 2 weeks business travel in Phillipines (Manilla)? I am travelling from India.

Comment: Are you an Indian citizen?

Comment: yes I am an india citizen

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're an Indian citizen then unfortunately India is not on the [list of countries](http://www.dfa.gov.ph/index.php/list-of-countries-for-21-day-visa) that can enter the Philippines visa-free for a short period (normally 30 days but it varies). If hold a different citizenship you can check that list to see if you qualify.

If you don't qualify you need a visa, here are the [visa guidelines](http://www.dfa.gov.ph/index.php/list-of-countries-for-21-day-visa). And here's the relevant part:

> **STANDARD PROCEDURE/MINIMUM REQUIREMENTS FOR APPLYING A TEMPORARY VISITOR'S VISA**
>
> Application for a temporary visitor's visa must be made in person. In the case of a minor under eighteen (18) years of age, the application may be made for him by a person who, in the opinion of the consular officer, is responsible for his/her welfare. The minor, not an infant in arms, shall be required to appear at the Consulate for interview, together with the person making the application for him/her.
>
> Applicants for temporary visitor's visa should normally apply at the Philippine Embassy or Consulate that has jurisdiction over their place of residence. While some visa applicants may apply at any Philippine Embassy or Consulate abroad, others are only allowed to apply his/her visa at the Philippine Embassy or Consulate in his country of origin or legal residence.
>
> The following are the minimum requirements for applying a temporary visitor's visa:
>
> 1. Passport/Travel Document Valid for at least six (6) months beyond
>      the intended period of stay in the Philippines
> 2. Duly Accomplished Visa application forms
> 3. Passport Photos (2 pieces)
> 4. Proof of bona fide status as tourist or businessman
> 5. Confirmed tickets for return or onward journey to the next port of destination
> 6. Payment of Visa Fee

The [Philippine Embassy in New Delhi](http://newdelhipe.dfa.gov.ph/index.php/2014-04-14-03-10-05/78-consular-services/108-visa-application-requirements) echos the above and recommends you apply at least two weeks in advance -- if you're applying at a different consulate then the timing may be different. If you're travelling for business you should have an invite letter from the company your are visiting indicating:

> applicant's travel to the Philippines, expected duration of stay and number of entries applied for (single entry/ multiple entry valid for 6 months or 1 year )

I'm afraid I can't find details of how much it would cost.

Comment: Thanks SpaceDog! your answer is very informative. This was exactly I was looking for. really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right link. 9A: Temporary Visitor's Visa for Business (Multiple Entry 1 Year validity) Fees - 7,680.00 INR